# How to modify data sending by application to the server?

Tags: network

Let's suppose that I have a simple application which is sending data to the server (placed not in my network), for example `0 1 2 3 4 5` (explicit data) in one second delay between each other. Is it possible to intercept part of this data, modify it and send like it was send by my application? How to do this? What should I know?

I know this question is kind of fatuously but I'm really curious about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have authentication then it is very straightforward to send spoofed data.

Luckily these this feature exists at various levels to prevent spoofing.

TCP/IP offers basic end to end connectivity, so an attacker needs to conduct a man in the middle attack. This consists of persuading A that the attacker is B and persuading B that the attacker is A. This way the data cab be altered.

In order to prevent man in the middle attacks, strong authentication is used, which is what HTTPS does - the client knows the identifier, or certificate, that the server has, and if the attacker tries to pretend to be the server it would not be able to authenticate itself unless it has the right certificate.

If we exclude man in the middle attacks, the only other way to change the data sent to the server is by compromising one of the end points, either the client or server.